# Trac unable to work with Subversion

Tags: svn, solaris, bug-tracking, trac

I have Collabnet Subversion 1.6.9, Trac 0.11.6, Python 2.6.1 from Sun's Webstack, Sunfreeware.com's swig 1.3.36 running on Solaris 10 5/09 SPARC.

I have these error code when open Trac page.

```
Serving on 0.0.0.0:8000 view at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
/opt/webstack/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/libsvn/fs.py:7: RuntimeWarning: Python C API version mismatch for module _fs: This Python has API version 1013, module _fs has version 1011.
  import _fs
/opt/webstack/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/libsvn/fs.py:7: RuntimeWarning: Python C API version mismatch for module swig_runtime_data4: This Python has API version 1013, module swig_runtime_data4 has version 1011.
  import _fs
/opt/webstack/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/libsvn/core.py:7: RuntimeWarning: Python C API version mismatch for module _core: This Python has API version 1013, module _core has version 1011.
  import _core
/opt/webstack/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/libsvn/delta.py:7: RuntimeWarning: Python C API version mismatch for module _delta: This Python has API version 1013, module _delta has version 1011.
  import _delta
/opt/webstack/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/libsvn/repos.py:7: RuntimeWarning: Python C API version mismatch for module _repos: This Python has API version 1013, module _repos has version 1011.
  import _repos
```

Please advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning is ignorable.

Previously, I had a problem browsing the source on Trac.
After I reconfigured the subversion to run its webserver on Apache instead of svnserve, I am able to browse the source.

It's possible that `viewvc` must be installed to be able to browse the source through HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

the error message is complaining about the libsvn is build against some older version of python. try rebuild that library and instruction is [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSubversion). (i am not on Solaris..., so i did not try it myself...)

Comment: how i know which version of Python has API version 1011?